# How to create more complex Lucene query strings?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net, information-retrieval

This question is a spin-off from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532365/how-to-get-more-out-of-lucene-net) question.
My inquiry is two-fold, but because both are related I think it is a good idea to put them together.

- How to programmatically create queries. I know I could start creating strings and get that string parsed with the query parser. But as I gather bits and pieces of information from other resources, there is a programattical way to do this.
- What are the syntax rules for the Lucene queries?

--EDIT--

I'll give a requirement example for a query I would like to make:
Say I have 5 fields:

1. First Name
2. Last Name
3. Age
4. Address
5. Everything

All fields are optional, the last field should search over all the other fields.
I go over every field and see if it's IsNullOrEmpty(). If it's not, I would like to append a part of my query so it adds the relevant search part.
First name and last name should be exact matches and have more weight then the other fields. Age is a string and should exact match. Address can varry in order. Everything can also varry in order.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) class to compose query objects. Create one of these and add() other Query objects to it to create a larger, disjunctive query:

- BooleanQuery q = new BooleanQuery();
- q.add(qFirstName, Occur.SHOULD);
- q.add(qLastName, Occur.SHOULD);
- ...

Atomic queries can be built with the Term and TermQuery classes.

(Links and example are for Lucene Java, but .NET should be similar.)