# Similarity between different length vectors containing related items

Tags: r, vector, compare, analytics, similarity

I have a vector (V1) with which I need to calculate the similarity of other vectors (ex V2,V3 ... ) which may be of different lengths.
The different angle here is that the elements inside the vectors are itself similar to each other.

```
V1 = c("a","b","c")
V2 = c("a","d","e","f","g")
V3 = c("b","c","f")
```

The elements are similar to each other for example:

```
      a      b        c       d       e       f      g
a   1.00    0.18    0.01    0.96    0.12    0.46    0.73
b           1.00    0.07    0.36    0.13    0.47    0.92
c                   1.00    0.88    0.62    0.65    0.31
d                           1.00    0.86    0.96    0.55
e                                   1.00    0.25    0.91
f                                           1.00    0.13
g                                                   1.00
```

The usual similarity methods like cosine similarity, correlation do not make use of the similarity between the elements of the vectors.I want to calculate the similarity between V1,V2 and V3.

Expected outcome:

```
    V1  V2  V3
V1  1   x   y
V2      1   z
V3          1
```

Comment: As your question is related to similarity measures on sets and not specific to R, you might get better answers on Cross Validated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post it there

Comment: Are these things sets or vectors?

Comment: These are sets. In the question I meant R vectors.I'll change it there

Comment: If there sets you can do a one-of-k-coding and compute cosine similarity, or poly-kernel, or whatever you like. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121217/cosine-similarity-of-vectors-of-different-lengths?rq=1) (Python example, but the principle is the same.

Comment: How the data relates to the diagonal matrix you provided? Could you provide the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added it in the question