# Comparison of two documents in python

Tags: python, tf-idf, n-gram, word2vec, cosine-similarity

Given two documents, I wish to calculate the similarity between them. I have measures to find out the cosine distance, N-Gram and tf-idf using this:
[This is a previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380394/simple-implementation-of-n-gram-tf-idf-and-cosine-similarity-in-python)

I wish to know, what further needs to be done using these functions.

Also, I have tried implementing Word2Vec, following which I tried finding similarities using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(Words)):
    print i
    for k in range(len(Words)):
        net_sim = 0.0
        for j in range(len(Words.ix[i]['A'])):
            sim = 0.0
            for l in range(len(Words.ix[k]['A'])):
                if sim < model.similarity(Words.ix[i]['A'][j],Words.ix[k]['A'][l]):
                    sim = model.similarity(Words.ix[i]['A'][j],Words.ix[k]['A'][l])
            net_sim += sim
        Similarity.ix[i][k] = net_sim/len(Words.ix[i]['A'])
```

For ever word in a given document, I try to find the most similar word in the second document and add their similarity. Then, I divide by the number of words, in order to normalize it to a range of 0 to 1.
Here, Words is a DataFrame, consisting of words of different documents, in separate rows and model is a Word2Vec model. This process takes a lot of time and I wish to optimize it and thereby looking for different approaches

Comment: Please show us the code you already have!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22577329/6350407

Comment: Please show us the code **you** already have! Sorry, but SO is not there for putting the code together you found somewhere else. You have to show at least some effort.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to SO and would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're focused into using these functions described by you, it should be easy to implement by reading [nltk wiki](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/wiki), but I don't know if this is the best way to compare the simmilarity between them.

As stated in the [difflib docs](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) page, you may also use their package to compare files and sequences.

> This module provides classes and functions for **comparing sequences**. It
>   can be used for example, for **comparing files**, and can produce
>   difference information in various formats, including HTML and context
>   and unified diffs.
>
> For comparing directories and files, see also, the [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html#module-filecmp) module.

---

More specifically, you can use [`difflib.SequenceMatcher()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) to compare sequences of text.

*Example:*

```
import difflib

# passing strings
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, str1, str2)

# reading files
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, file1.read(), file2.read())
```

---

For more examples and tutorials, see:

[PyMOTW - difflib](https://pymotw.com/2/difflib/)

Comment: No, I need to find the similarity in range 0 to 1.
I tried the Word2Vec approach but it takes a lot of time and I need a faster program for bigger data