# Highlighting in lucene

Tags: lucene, highlight

I am stuck .I am using a Reader to extract the content of document and I would like to highlight it in search time .
How can I do that ?
Someone can show some code please ?

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

lemoos, Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189366/lucene-net-search-result-to-highlight-search-keywords) and [Nick Hrycan's blog post](http://hrycan.com/2009/10/25/lucene-highlighter-howto/). Note that this is highly version-dependent, so you will probably need to tweak this to your version of Lucene.

BTW, [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) has much simpler highlighting - if you have not invested a lot of time and effort in Lucene, you may consider switching to Solr.