# Lucene.net and google snippet similar

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, lucene.net

I need to create a search engine that dynamically extracts full text search results with a snippet (like Google). I have read some posts talking about Lucene.net.
It's a great product (I need c# solution) but does it have summarizing features too, like Sql Server full search.

I have searched for a solution but I didn't find any. Some ideas?
I've put so many blob objecst into sql server and I must to create a good search, like Google.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene has a .Net port called [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)

There is also a `Highlighter` class for Lucene.Net that can be used to highlight (create a summary) of search results.  See:

- [How to highlight a phrase on results from Lucene.Net](http://davidpodhola.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-highlight-phrase-on-results-from.html)
- [Lucene.Net Search result to highlight search keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189366/lucene-net-search-result-to-highlight-search-keywords)

Comment: Wonderful Kragen: I searched it for days without finding. Unfortunaly documentation is not so ordered. I'll try it asap. Thanks.

Comment: Kragen your first link has only broken link, but I think I can use this: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/contrib-highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html

Comment: @Merlinox The first link definitely works, try it on a different PC / Internet connection.

Comment: sorry... I spoke about internal link, of your first link. But I found all. Thanks!